# Как отобразить отсутствующие в dataframe страны? R, ggplot2

Tags: dataframe, r, rstudio, ggplot2

У меня есть датафрейм clustering_map с координатами стран, выполнена кластеризация, я хочу нарисовать карту мира. Но в нём не все страны. Как сделать так, чтобы отсутствующие тоже отобразились на карте? Как соединить с полной картой мира?

```
ggplot(clustering_map, aes(long, lat, group = group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = cluster), color = 1)+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C") # разбить на кластеры по цветам
```

Comment: Добавьте первым слоем все страны мира  как фон, можно использовать другой пространственный датасет, а уже сверху положить слой со своей выборкой стран

Comment: Закиньте пример данных и свой код, чтобы пример решения получился осмысленным.